# Symfony update form field base on a Symfony event

Tags: forms, symfony, events

I'm working with Symfony to handle forms :

I have Color Type  with fixed values :

[image]

I need to add other value to this fixed list base on form event

The idea is when i render the form, check if another color value exist and push this value to the current list

```
 ->add('color', ColorType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'invalid_message' => 'La couleur est incorrecte.',
                'choice_label' => function ($value) {
                    return $value;
                },
            ])
 ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, [$this, 'onCustomForm'])
```

I added an event to get the color value :

```
 public function onCustomForm(FormEvent $event)
    {

        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $form->getConfig()->getData();
        $color = $data->getColor();
//        dd($color);
}
```

i want to add the color value to the existant list values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that with the Symfony ColorType as their is no option to add or restrict color.

You have to use a ChoiceType

```
public function onCustomForm(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    /** @var SettingData $data */
    $data = $event->getData();
    // If the setting data is already set
    if ($data && !$data->getData()->isEmpty()) {
        $apiColors = ...// Fetch your colors from api
        $originalColors = $form->get('color')->getConfig()->getData();
         $form->add('color', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => array_merge($apiColors, $originalColors),
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false
         ]);
    }
}
```

In fact adding an existing fields ('color') will remplace it.

So, that's how you update it with you new data.

Comment: no, i have a fixed list yet,  and i get another value from API, i want to add this value to the existant list,

Comment: Maybe you could have precise this in your question ? Can you edit it and provide this new information

Comment: i updated the question, i have a fixed list of colors, and i should check if another value exist ( a value coming from the api) and push this value to the existant list